# Antd Sankey: Normalize height of nodes

Tags: charts, antd

I am using antd charts 1.4.2 and implemented a sankey:

[image: antd sankey]

The sankey is always 800px high and I cannot change it?!? Tried height, autoFit... in config.

Ultimatively, my goal is to normalize the height of a node. E.g. in the example, "Baulücke klassisch" > "n/a" has a count of 2. So the node should be a fixed height that I define (e.g 10px*2). Currently, the sankey is stretched to 800px height and therefore it is stretching the nodes too. Making them appear very thick and high even though they only contain little data.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it like that now which is basically setting the height based on the sum of the value:

```
const valueSum = (config.data as Datum).reduce((total: number, obj:Datum) => {
        return total + obj.value;
}, 0);

const config = {
        data
        sourceField: 'source',
        targetField: 'target',
        weightField: 'value',
        height: valueSum *12,
        nodeWidthRatio: 0.004,
        nodePaddingRatio: 0.008,
        colorField: 'source',
        autoFit:false,
      } as SankeyConfig;

return (
   <Sankey style={style} {...config} />
)
```